# How to include two phase types to look for in `oc wait` command

Tags: openshift

I'm editing a script that calls the `oc wait` command with these parameters:

```shell
oc wait --for=condition=Ready pod --field-selector=status.phase!=Terminating -l app=foo --timeout=55s
```

The above command executes successfully, but I need to check for `InvalidImageName` in addition to `Terminating` in the `--field-selector=status.phase` option.

I've tried

```shell
oc wait --for=condition=Ready pod --field-selector=status.phase!=Terminating||InvalidImageName -l app=foo --timeout=55s
```

But that does not work.

What is the correct way to format this command?